# Android application only shows white screen on second run after installation

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am at my wits end with this issue.

When I deploy the app using release configuration, or install it via sideloading, the first run (right after installation) works perfectly.

If I try to run the app again after closing it (by finding the app in the menu) the app opens but stays on a white screen.

Is this an issue anyone has encountered before? Is there a functional difference between the app opening for the first time ever and opening a second time?

Edit: Code that runs at launch

Main Activity

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {            
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Droid.ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
        Syncfusion.XForms.Android.PopupLayout.SfPopupLayoutRenderer.Init();
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);

        var  dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "ForSiteSQLite.db3");

        if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
            {
                var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);//This is where we can make the notifications do special things

                if (key == "Type")
                {
                    if (Intent.Extras.GetString(key) == "Case Assignment")
                    {
                        LoadApplication(new App(dbPath, "Case Assignment"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LoadApplication(new App(dbPath));
        }

        int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
        {
            if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(resultCode))
            {
                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(CurrentContext.ApplicationContext, "default")
                .SetContentTitle("Error")
                .SetContentText(GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorString(resultCode));


                // Build the notification:
                Notification notification = builder.Build();

                // Get the notification manager:
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

                // Publish the notification:
                const int notificationId = 0;
                notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
            }
            else
            {
                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(CurrentContext.ApplicationContext, "default")
                .SetContentTitle("Error")
                .SetContentText("This device is not supported");


                // Build the notification:
                Notification notification = builder.Build();

                // Get the notification manager:
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

                // Publish the notification:
                const int notificationId = 0;
                notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
                Finish();
            }
        }

        CreateNotificationChannel();
    }

    void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
            // support library). There is no need to create a notification
            // channel on older versions of Android.
            return;
        }

        var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                                              "FCM Notifications",
                                              NotificationImportance.Default)
        {

            Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
        };

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public App(string dbPath)
    {
        RegisterSyncfusion();
        InitializeComponent();
        database = new LocalDB(dbPath);
        MainPage = new LoginPage();
    }

private void RegisterSyncfusion()
    {
        //Register Syncfusion license
        Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("REDACTED");
    }
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        vm = new LoginViewModel();

        if (Helpers.Settings.Username != "" && Helpers.Settings.Password != "")
        {
            chkRemember.IsChecked = true;

            txtUsername.Text = Helpers.Settings.Username;
            txtPassword.Text = Helpers.Settings.Password;

            AttemptLogin();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show the code that runs first on opening of the App?

Comment: This is not normal behaviour. Please provide your code and manifest file for us to work on.

Comment: After the first time white screen then it works normally?

Comment: Code added to OP, for some reason it won't let me embed the manifest, suggestions?

No, the app can effectively only be run once, and then it has to be uninstalled and reinstalled to run again, otherwise it is only a blank white screen

Comment: I actually may have discovered something while formatting the code for the question. Is it possible that an intent is being passed in on the second and further runs that doesn't get passed in on the first?